# HTML 5 input type tel add underscore option on mobile device

Tags: html, mobile, angular6, mobile-safari

I have an HTML input type tel and all I want to do is to accept numbers and underscore.
The issue is that I can't see the underscore on my mobile device(Safari,Chrome).

```
 <input placeholder="placeholder" type="tel">
```

How can I add the underscore option to the input on the mobile device using HTML?

I'm working with Angular 6, if it matters.

Comment: It seems like what you want is just *not* a tel input.

Comment: can you provide your working code?

Comment: it doesn't need to be tel but I need it to be a numeric keyboard  on mobile device
```
      <mat-form-field class="w-100">
              <input matInput placeholder="xxx"
                     appOnlyNumbers
                     type="tel" inputmode="text"
                     formControlName="xxx" autofocus required>
              <mat-icon matSuffix>local_taxi</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
```